# Web2py Alphabetical Pagination

Tags: web2py

I have a Listings page for Businesses and I want a Alphabetical pagination/menu like in the attached screenshot. I want to do it in web2py

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question mentions an attached screenshot, but none is shown.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to attach, as I dont have the priviliges to attach, and I didnt realize the same.

Answer (score 2):

In the view, maybe something like:

```
{{import string}}
{{for browse_type in ['category', 'listing', 'locality', 'brand']:}}
{{=CAT('Browse by ', browse_type, ' ',
      *[A(letter, _href=URL('default', 'browse', args=[browse_type, letter]))
        for letter in string.uppercase])}}
{{pass}}
```

That will generate a set of links like /yourapp/default/browse/category/A, etc. Of course, you'll have to fill out the HTML a little more to get the exact format/layout you want -- the above is just an example of how to generate the links.

Then in the controller:

```
def browse():
    if len(request.args) < 2:
        redirect(URL('default', 'somewhere'))
    [code to generate items to browse based on browse type and letter]
```

Note, request.args(0) will contain the browse type (i.e., "category", "listing", etc.), and request.args(1) will contain the letter (i.e., "A", "B", etc.). You can use those values to generate the appropriate query, which will depend on how you have structured your data.

If some of the letters won't have any items, you might consider removing those links or making them inactive. This will require a database query before generating the pagination links so you know which links to show/make active -- to minimize db hits, you should probably cache that query for some time (or better yet, cache the complete pagination HTML).